# Someone knows about service "perlfiddle"?

Tags: perl

I could not find service to run Perl scripts like http://jsbin.com, http://jsfiddle.net, http://sqlfiddle.com, http://phpfiddle.org, http://pythonfiddle.com. Somebody knows a link to services for Perl?

Comment: http://ideone.com/ comes to mind for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used http://ideone.com/ pretty successfully.

I am sure some more thorough searches would dig up some more places too.

Comment: FYI - Perl version is v5.12.1

Answer (score 5):

Also http://perltuts.com, which has some tutorial material as well as an evaluator.

Comment: FYI - Perl version is v5.14.2